# grep -v not working inside shell script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep

I have this line inside my shell script:

```
tomcatPID=$(ps -ef | grep tomcat | grep $TOMCAT_ACCOUNT | grep -v grep | grep -v restart | awk '{print $2}')
```

I made sure that the `$TOMCAT_ACCOUNT` part is okay. What I have problems with is the `grep -v`. That works in the terminal, but when I put it in the shell script, it ignores that `grep` and gives me results that include it.

The question is: Why is `grep -v` being ignored inside a shell script but on the terminal it works fine?

For example:

Let's say I'm working under `become application`, so am at `application@servername` and in the terminal I run:

```
tomcatPID=$(ps -ef | grep tomcat | grep application | grep -v grep | grep -v restart | awk '{print $2}')
```

Output: `42345` which only the processID for the tomcat that is running my application.

If I create `file.sh` and inside I have the exact same:

```
tomcatPID=$(ps -ef | grep tomcat | grep $TOMCAT_ACCOUNT | grep -v grep | grep -v restart | awk '{print $2}')
```

and then run it using: `./file.sh`
output: `42345 6534` which are the processID of my `tomcat` and the `processID` of the `grep` that I'm running. Hence, the `grep -v grep` to avoid getting that second processID but it gets ignored inside the `.sh` file.

Comment: What is the question? Can you think of any information that you could give that might help us help you answer it? In general a series of grep commands being piped into awk is pretty inefficient, awk itself can do the pattern matching. Do you have "pgrep"? Maybe add a "-u $TOMCAT_ACCOUNT" to the `ps` command and remove one grep? Show us the output of `ps -ef | grep tomcat`.

Comment: let me explain it a little better: @icarus

the problem is grep -v
If I run this line in the terminal it outputs one processID
If I run it inside a shell script, it returns 4 processIDs because it is ignoring the grep -v part.

Comment: Could you use `tomcatPID=$(pgrep tomcat)` instead. Read  `man pgrep`.

Comment: the question is: Why is grep -v being ignored inside a shell script but on the terminal it works fine??

Comment: @Lipaw11 to help answer that, I suggest you remove the `| awk '{print $2}'` and then add `echo "$tomcatPID"` so we can see exactly what it is matching

Comment: `tomcatPID=$(ps -fu "$TOMCAT_USER" | awk '/[t]omcat/ && !/[r]estart/ {print $2}')` maybe

Comment: have you look at `alias grep` ?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the most simple case you can create of a command and its output that supports your claim.

Comment: Does it ignore _both_ `grep -v` invocations, or only one of them?

Comment: Yes, it ignores both accounts of grep -v

Comment: @roaima, I'll give that a try

Comment: -1 please [show the output of the command which @steeldriver asked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/653605/grep-v-not-working-inside-shell-script#comment1228464_653605), that should not be the PID of the grep but your script PID itself  most probably. without showing that, no one can guess what does grep returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggesting a better way to get the PID that you want, use `pgrep`. This example will find my java tomcat process

```
TOMCAT_ACCOUNT=tomcat
ps -fu "$TOMCAT_ACCOUNT"
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
tomcat     678     1  0 Jun04 ?        00:47:49 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dja
tomcat    1900   678  0 Jun04 ?        00:00:02 /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin --accep

pgrep -u "$TOMCAT_ACCOUNT" java
678
```

If you've got very particular requirements (it must have `tomcat` in a process command being run by the `$_TOMCAT_ACCOUNT` user and must not contain `restart` anywhere in the line) you could use this

```
TOMCAT_ACCOUNT=tomcat
ps -fu "$TOMCAT_ACCOUNT" | awk '/.[t]omcat/ && !/[r]estart/ {print $2}'
678
```

Comment: Thank you Roaima!!!! The second solution is exactly what I needed!!! :)